# Set CSS3 filter for only background image

Tags: html, css

I have divs with content inside - when I set filter:grayscale(100%), it makes the content grayscale too. How can I make the filter only affect the background-image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `:before` selector

I made an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/vcwjn0q8/)